# Как на Linux из jar-файла узнать путь расположения jar-файла

Tags: java, linux, centos, jar

Сталкиваюсь с проблемой запуска jar файла.
Если я нахожусь в директории "/usr/tscripts/" и из этой директории даю команду

```
java -jar /usr/tscripts/check.jar
```

Скрипт отрабатывает хорошо, если я только вошел на ПК и нахожусь в директории "/root"
и с этой директории запускаю команду, то нечего не происходит
Подозреваю что надо либо переменные среды добавить или как-то в команде указать путь "/usr/tscripts/" как home
Подскажите как правильно запускать скрипт из любой директории?

В ходе выяснения кода скрипта я выяснил следующее

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

File file = new File(path);

  try {
     System.out.println(String.valueOf(file.getCanonicalFile()));
  } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

На Windows машине код выдает путь откуда был запущен jar-файл.
На Linux машине он выдает путь текущей директории.

Естественно если мы находимся "/root" jar-файл выдает "/root",
если перейти в директорию "/usr/tscripts/" там ввести команду то все работает. Это путь очень важен, так как дальше считывает файл "settings.ini" который находится в директории "/usr/tscripts/"
Вопрос немного изменился как написать код, который на Linux машине выведет путь расположения jar-файла?

P.S. Писать путь внутри кода не выход

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо что не оставили незамеченным,  решил проблему следующим образом.
Командой

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

Определяем платформу.
Если Windows выше изложенный код работает идеально.

Если Linux то применяем следующее

```
String path = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

Данная команда на платформе Windows выводит путь к классу что в моей задаче как-бы не требуется.
Но на платформе Linux выводит `путь/файл.jar`
Что по сути мне и нужно, ну а как отделить путь от имени файла это уже совсем другая история.

P.S. информацию подчерпнул от [сюда](http://developer-remarks.blogspot.com/2012/12/system-get-properties.html)

Answer (score 1):

> как-то в команде указать путь "/usr/tscripts/" как home

Что бы понять, что конкретно происходит, надо войти в окно терминала и выполнить команду:

```
java -jar /usr/tscripts/check.jar
```

Вы увидите сообщение об ошибке. Скорее всего, там будет сказано, что "не могу найти ....". Если то, что не удаётся найти, действительно расположено в каталоге */usr/tscripts/*, то простейшее решение проблемы таково:

1. В любом каталоге, который включён в *$PATH* (например - /usr/bin, ~/bin и т.д.) создаём файл скрипта с произвольным именем. Например *p_redator.sh*.
2. В этот файл помещаем три строки:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   cd /usr/tscripts/
   java -jar ./check.jar
   ```
3. Выполняем команду  *chmod 0755 p_redator.sh*
4. Наслаждаемся жизнью

Comment: Я на linux машине в терминале ввожу "java -jar /usr/tscripts/check.jar"  и если я нахожусь в директории "/usr/tscripts/" то все проходит нормально, если из любой другой директории то скрипт нечего не выдает, Спасибо за подсказку, есть еще идея "/usr/tscripts/" добавить в переменные среды PATH

Comment: @p_redator - " скрипт нечего не выдает". Есть большие сомнения, по поводу того, что **ничего** не выдаёт. Хотелось бы посмотреть протокол ваших действий в терминале. А так-же результат выполнения команды *ls -l /usr/bin/p_redator.sh* и команды *cat /usr/bin/p_redator.sh*

Comment: создавать скрипт на запуск скрипта мне кажется не совсем правильно, проще уже писать весь код на bash, прорабатываю вариант запуск скрипта с аргументами, в котором будет лежать путь

Comment: @p_redator - "создавать скрипт на запуск скрипта" - Звучит достаточно глупо, согласен. Однако этот приём весьма часто используется при переносе виндовозных программ на люних. У них разные окружения и разные правила поиска файлов в ФС. Поэтому, если переносим скрипт, отлаженный на винде, в люних, то возможно два варианта - 1) править исходный крипт 2) Написать "оболочечный" скрипт, который выполняет все нужные настройки. Очень часто бывает, что используют второй путь.